# Using Parameter Pack Expansion to Generate a Constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using std::vector;

enum EventType {
    EventType_Collision,
    EventType_Accelerate,
    EventType_Glide
};

template<class T, EventType... events>
class A {
private:
    static unsigned short CalcBitMask(EventType e) { return 1 << e; }
    static constexpr unsigned short listeners = 0 | CalcBitMask(events)...;
protected:
    //static constexpr int InternalGetType() { return 0; }
public:
    static constexpr int GetType() { return T::InternalGetType(); }
    static constexpr int GetListeners() { return listeners; }
};

class B : public A<B, EventType_Accelerate, EventType_Collision > {
    friend class A<B, EventType_Accelerate, EventType_Collision>;
protected:
    static constexpr int InternalGetType() { return 1; }
};
```

I am trying to create a bitmask based on the `EvenType` arguments passed into the template. Unfortunately the number of `EvenTypes` passed is variadic. But since we have all the arguments at compile time it seems like it should be more than possible to calculate a value based on the given arguments at compile time as a `constexpr`. What I get on the other hand is:

`expression did not evaluate to a constant`

For the listeners variable. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

P.S. On a completely unrelated note if anyone has any idea how I can eliminate the lengthy friend class declaration without taking a performance hit and keeping the `InternalGetType()` function hidden I would love and greatly appreciate hearing it.

**Edit**

In response to a recent suggestion I am limited to using C++14

**Edit**

This is what I have done to make it work using recursive template calls
crtp.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using std::vector;

enum EventType {
    EventType_Collision,
    EventType_Accelerate,
    EventType_Glide
};

template<class T, EventType... events>
class A {
private:
    template <EventType Last>
    static constexpr unsigned short BitCalc() {
        return 1 << Last;
    }

    template <EventType First, EventType Second, EventType ...Rest>
    static constexpr unsigned short BitCalc() {
        return BitCalc<First>() | BitCalc<Second, Rest...>();
    }
    static constexpr unsigned short listeners = BitCalc<events...>();
protected:
    //static constexpr int InternalGetType() { return 0; }
public:
    static constexpr int GetType() { return T::InternalGetType(); }
    static constexpr int GetListeners() { return listeners; }
};

class B : public A<B, EventType_Accelerate, EventType_Collision > {
    friend class A<B, EventType_Accelerate, EventType_Collision>;
protected:
    static constexpr int InternalGetType() { return 1; }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ctrp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<bitset>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::getchar;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    B b;
    cout << "Bitmask: " << std::bitset<16>(b.GetListeners());
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use C++17, fold expressions (see HolyBlackCat's answer) is (IMHO) a way really simple and elegant to solve the problem.

If you can't use C++17...  the best I can imagine is the development of a `static constexpr` method for `class A`; something as follows

```
constexpr static unsigned short calcCombinedBitMask ()
 {
   using unused = unsigned short [];

   unsigned short  ret { 0 };

   (void)unused { 0, ret |= CalcBitMask(events)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

So you can initialize `listener` in this way

```
static constexpr unsigned short listeners = calcCombinedBitMask();
```

For C++11, I suggest a solution a little different from you own

```
static constexpr unsigned short CalcBitMask (EventType e)
 { return 1 << e; }

static constexpr unsigned short BitCalc()
 { return 0; }

template <EventType First, EventType ... Rest>
static constexpr unsigned short BitCalc()
 { return CalcBitMask(First) | BitCalc<Rest...>(); }
```

Comment: Sweet, that will do it! I swear the things you can do with templates, it's amazing thank you. Just to make sure I'm thinking about things correctly from a performance perspective there is no difference between calling `calcBitMask()` each time instead of using the `listeners` variable since the function will be precalculated and inlined anyways right?

Comment: @Ryoku - yes, variadic templates are really great. For the performance question... I'm not really an expert but... take in count that `listener` is a `static constexpr` member; so is (quite) surely precalculated  compile time. `calbBitMask()`, and `calcComninedBitMask()`, are **methods**. So they can be used compile time (by example, to initialize a `consexpr` variable as `listener`) or run time (by example, to assign a new value to a not-constant variable). So if you use `listener` you use a compile time computed value; if you use `calcBitMask()`, you can demand it's calculus run time.

Comment: Okay so I just ran into an error. I was finally able to build the code in my system and it comes up with the error `'ret': declaration is not allowed in 'constexpr' function body` which I guess is it's way of telling me I can't use variables in a constexpr. Which seems strange since its within its scope.

Comment: @Ryoku - sorry: I've forgotten that only starting from C++14 `constexpr` function can be so complicated. Are you compiling C++11 or C++14? If you need a C++11 solution, I can try to create a recursive version of `calcCombinedBitMask()`.

Comment: I am compiling C++14, I found a way to make it work using recursive template functions, but I'm still a little shaky on them to be honest so I would appreciate it (if its not too much trouble), if you could take a look at the code I just added to the question and see if a) I got it right, and/or b) there is a better/more elegant way of doing it

Comment: @Ryoku - strange, because my `calcCombinedBitMask()` compile in C++14 with my g++ and my clang++; I suggest to check if the C++14 compilation is enabled. Anyway, it seems to me that your C++11 `BitCalc()` is acceptable. But I don't like (question of taste, I suppose) a ground case based on a significant calculus and a recursive case based on first/second/rest. I've modified my answer with a modified version of your solution with a trivial ground case (return 0), a recursive case with first/rest (no second) and with recycle of your original `CalcBitMask()`.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. I think it won't compile on my end because apparently C++14 on visual studio 2015 does not support "extended constexpr" which is what I think we want here, and unfortunately I have to make sure my code compiles with 2015. On the more important note, thanks a ton, your code looks much cleaner than mine, a much more natural halt I feel.

Answer (score 2):

That asks for [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). Note that they're a relatively new feature, added in C++17.

```
static constexpr unsigned short listeners = (CalcBitMask(events) | ...);
```

Also you forgot to make `CalcBitMask()` `constexpr`.

Comment: Wow thank you, I am embarrassed to say how long that was taking me to figure out.... Okay so now when I run the program the optimizing compiler stops working and eventually it spits out a `syntax error '...'` for the initialization of listeners. Any thoughts on why it might be doing that? Aww man @max66 your so right. Okay this would have been awesome and the way to go but I'm limited to using C++14 unfortunately. Any other ideas? As a side note what a great addition to templates way to go C++17

Comment: @Ryoku Then max66's answer should help.